# Application .exe.config corrupted during unexpected turn off

Tags: c#, .net, config, app-config

When shutting down unexpectedly my computer the application .exe.config file got corrupted.
During the shutting down I save the configuration file using `System.Configuration.configuration.Save()`

```
 public static void Save(bool i_SaveToRegistry)
        {
            SaveAsAdamConfigBackUp();
            System.Configuration.Configuration.Save();

            if (i_SaveToRegistry)
            {
                SaveToRegistry();
                SaveGlobalSettingExtention();
            }

            OnSaved(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

and while it's happening I turn off the machine.
Before this i copy the current config and create a backup so I can update it if it got corrunpted.

corrunpted means it got empty. Both the files.

```
public static void SaveAsAdamConfigBackUp()
        {
            try
            {
                string configFilePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Adam.Exe.config";
                string backupConfigFile = configFilePath + ".Backup";

                if (File.Exists(configFilePath))
                {
                    File.Copy(configFilePath, backupConfigFile, true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Adam.LogError("An exception occurred during save configuraton backup file.\n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Any ideas why the both files got corrupted ?
How can I solve it ?

Comment: Did you check event viewer?You may get some clue.

Comment: The event viewer only show the error side by side ov configuration file - because the configuration file is empty

Comment: "Empty" and "corrupted" are generally considered different things.

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko - corrupted means that the configuration file and the backup got empty - blank page.

Comment: Thank you for clarification that `corrupted` means `empty`. Next step is to figure out why. Do you have any code which is altering the content of the config file before the copy operation takes place?

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko yes. I only use the Save() method of the System.Configuration.Configuration

Comment: @Amy sure. Any ideas to solve it ?

Comment: @AdamBickels no, it's power loss.  During such events stuff can break in unexpected and unpredictable ways. To protect against this sort of event, use a battery backup.  There's no way to code around this - it's *power loss*.

Comment: `Copy` operation is not changing the content of the source hence the issue is happening earlier when `Save` is called or when the original config gets altered in the code. Try wrapping the `Save` and write to the log the exception details. Do the same for the code altering the original config.

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko, already done. In the case where I turn off the computer unexpectedly, even the event doesn't write to event viewer.

Comment: Can you post some of the code which is altering/saving the configuration file?

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko I added the code to the main question.

Comment: Thank you, it does make it very clear now +1. I would also be looking forward to the answer here, it is weird that config file gets cleared before `Save` is called.

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko I don't think that config files gets cleared before save is called. I think that the config file gets cleared during the save process some how. And thank you for trying to help me to solve this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150733/discussion-between-eugene-komisarenko-and-adam-bickels).